# How can I remove substring from an array and we are fetch data from the database?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.1

I want to remove only development and want to fetch rest of the array?

Menus is table having one column with below names:

- web Development
- App Development
- Digital stratergy
- graphic Team

I need this should be come in below fromat
web, graphic team, app, Digital stratergy

I am able to get in same order but unable to remove development.. I tried below code.
Thanks for help in advance.

```
foreach($requiredOrderForService as $index){
    echo  urldecode(strtoupper($this->Html->link($serv[$index]['Service']['name'],array('controller' => $serv[$index]['Service']['controller'],
               'action' => $serv[$index]['Service']['action'],$serv[$index]['Service']['id'],
               'admin' => false,
               'plugin' => false),array('class'=>'menuForFooter2'))));
    echo "<br>";

}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with `cakephp` so which array returns the names ? is it `$serv[$index]['Service']['name']` ?

Comment: yaa , I want that array only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with `cakephp` but based on the response to my comment you can do something like this,

```
foreach($requiredOrderForService as $index){
   echo  urldecode(strtoupper($this->Html->link(str_replace('Development','',$serv[$index]['Service']['name']),array('controller' => $serv[$index]['Service']['controller'],
           'action' => $serv[$index]['Service']['action'],$serv[$index]['Service']['id'],
           'admin' => false,
           'plugin' => false),array('class'=>'menuForFooter2'))));
   echo "<br>";

}
```

Comment: @user186730 Click on the triangle above 0 to the left of my answer to vote up. Click on the tick sign to accept it.